# how to make php wait seconds in between rest api calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I'm currently making calls to a api that returns xml! The Api which I'm using ajax for require 250 Milliseconds in between calls,  from what I understand ajax makes asynchronous calls so all the calls send off at the same time how do I force my php script once the call arrives to wait 250 milliseconds in between before send off the call. I tried to use setTimeout in js that didnt work
HTML

```html
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='13435'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='15339'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='14656'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='13447'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='12243'></div>
```

JS

```js
$(".grid-item").each(function(i) {
  var items = [];
  var prod_id = $(this).attr('data-grid');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
      grid: 'set',
      prod_id: prod_id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find('a\\:Inventory').each(function(index, value) {
        var name = $(this).find('Name').html();
        var age = $(this).find('Age').html();

        var display = `
          <div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 text-center no-padding'>
            <div class='col-xs-3 no-padding grid-data-box'>${name} </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3 no-padding grid-data-box'>${age}</div>
          </div>
        `;

        items.push({
          name: name,
          age: age,
        });

        $('[data-grid="'+prod_id+'"]').append(display)  ;
      });

      console.log(items);
    }
  });
});
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['grid'])){

echo file_get_contents(file_path) ; 
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you want to make the server-side code (PHP) wait 250ms before giving a response?  Do you want to make the Javascript wait 250ms between each request?

Comment: It sounds like you need to set the timeout in the js since if all ajax requests hit the php script at the same time it will still result in all the api requests firing at the same time.

Comment: Patrick,  either or  I just want to 250 ms between each call to the api, I tried to accomplish this both on the server side and on javascript I got nothing

Comment: @Tristan when I use settimeout in JS it didnt work because its asynchronous

Comment: @MikeUistervet Requiring the time between _each call_ is very different from requiring the time between _the request and the response_.  That's why I'm asking you to be precise about your ultimate objective.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding,  I mean in between each request, I noted that the Api requires 250 ms in between

Comment: do you have a solution for me?

Comment: Since ajax is async you can use .each index * timeout to stagger the ajax requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ajax is asynchronous you can stagger the ajax requests by multiplying the timeout by the `.each()` index. In the example below the first iteration of the each loop would have a timeout of 500ms, the second 1000ms, etc.

```
$(".grid-item").each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // add you ajax code here
    },500 * i);
});
```

Comment: Your a genius , something so simple but so powerful thanks